# laravel 4.2 retrieving data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

for my project i need to get the temperature from the mysql table based on them *command* column and *system_id*  and current_value which are listed on the table.

I am passing the values to .blade.php and try to display the values on my website.

in my BuildingController.php I have the following function

```
     public static function furnaceMap($building_id, $system_id)
  {
    $data['thisBldg'] = Building::find($building_id);
    $data['thisSystem'] = System::find($system_id);
    $data['boiler'] = 'boiler.jpg';



      $currentData = DeviceDataCurrent::where('system_id', $system_id)
      ->where('command', '1')   //i am only getting command 1 values
      ->orderby('id','ASC','command','ASC')
     //->take(100)
     ->get();
        $currentData = DeviceDataCurrent::where('system_id', $system_id);
        $currentData->whereIn('command', function($subquery)
        {
          $subquery->from('device_types')
           ->select('command')
           ->where('function', 'Temperature');
        });

        $currentData =$currentData
          ->orderby('id','ASC','command','ASC')
          ->get();
          //dd($currentData -> toArray());

    $data['apartments'] = [
      ['x-pos'=>"100", 'y-pos'=>"80" , 'state'=>"success", 'name'=>"Apt1"         ,'tag'=>"Temperature:", 'temp'=>"76" ."&deg"."F",  'status'=>"On" ,  'high'=>"80" , 'low'=>"70" , 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"250", 'y-pos'=>"80" , 'state'=>"warning", 'name'=>"Apt2"         ,'tag'=>"Temperature:", 'temp'=>"77" ."&deg"."F",  'status'=>"On" ,  'high'=>"80" , 'low'=>"70" , 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"400", 'y-pos'=>"80" , 'state'=>"success", 'name'=>"Apt3"         ,'tag'=>"Temperature:", 'temp'=>"55" ."&deg"."F",  'status'=>"Off",  'high'=>"80" , 'low'=>"45" , 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"550", 'y-pos'=>"80" , 'state'=>"success", 'name'=>"Apt4"         ,'tag'=>"Temperature:", 'temp'=>"67" ."&deg"."F",  'status'=>"On" ,  'high'=>"85" , 'low'=>"60" , 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"700", 'y-pos'=>"80" , 'state'=>"success", 'name'=>"Apt5"         ,'tag'=>"Temperature:", 'temp'=>"67" ."&deg"."F",  'status'=>"On" ,  'high'=>"85" , 'low'=>"60" , 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"100", 'y-pos'=>"335", 'state'=>"success", 'name'=>"DHW"          ,'tag'=>"Temperature:", 'temp'=>"113"."&deg"."F",  'status'=>"Off",  'high'=>"110", 'low'=>"90" , 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"215", 'y-pos'=>"335", 'state'=>"success", 'name'=>"CHW"          ,'tag'=>"Temperature:", 'temp'=>"132"."&deg"."F",  'status'=>"On" ,  'high'=>"135", 'low'=>"125", 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"390", 'y-pos'=>"270", 'state'=>"warning", 'name'=>"STACK"        ,'tag'=>"Temperature:", 'temp'=>"675"."&deg"."F",  'status'=>"On" ,  'high'=>"680", 'low'=>"660", 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"700", 'y-pos'=>"250", 'state'=>"warning", 'name'=>"RETURN"       ,'tag'=>"Temperature:", 'temp'=>"125"."&deg"."F",  'status'=>"On" ,  'high'=>"135", 'low'=>"110", 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"650", 'y-pos'=>"435", 'state'=>"success", 'name'=>"Make-up Water",'tag'=>"Water Amount:",'temp'=>"7"  .     "gal",  'status'=>"On" ,  'high'=>"25" , 'low'=>"10" , 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"550", 'y-pos'=>"225", 'state'=>"success", 'name'=>"Steam"        ,'tag'=>"Pressure:"   , 'temp'=>"12" ."&nbsp"."lb",'status'=>"On" ,  'high'=>"25" , 'low'=>"10" , 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ],
      ['x-pos'=>"455", 'y-pos'=>"435", 'state'=>"warning", 'name'=>"AQS"          ,'tag'=>"Temperature:", 'temp'=>"18" ."&deg"."F",  'status'=>"On" ,  'high'=>"25" , 'low'=>"10" , 'location'=>"loc", 'systemID'=>"xxxxxx" ]
      ];

    return View::make('buildings.furnace', $data);

  }
```

Based on the command column and system_id column I need to distribute the data.  for example if the system_id is 60 and command is 1  so the current_value is the value for my apt1, if the system_id is 61 and command is 1 the current_value is for my apt2 so on. I have done this far and seems like i dont really know what to do next to pass the data to temp. 
I will be so happy if anyone can help me on this problem.

Comment: You want to display the temperature?

Comment: yes! based on the command and system_id

Comment: for now i hardcoded the temperature. the next step is to establish the connection to the database and get the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed.

Please see the site for the answer
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/fetching-data-from-the-database